# what is the string maximum and minimum value in range validator in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I dont know what is the maximum and minimum value of string in RangeValidator in asp.net

is anyone have idea?
in such interview of asp.net company ask this question? so i want to know please help me out

thnx in advance

Comment: If you're interviewing for a position and don't know the answer to a question, it's better to answer honestly - "I don't know the answer to that.  If it came up, I'd look it up on MSDN or ask the question at StackOverflow".  Learning and knowing the material for real is important, but honesty is even more important.  If you're bluffing and exaggerating your experience, they are going to find out once you start working and are not as good as you claimed to be.  You'll be lucky to keep your job for any length of time unless the company is desperate or unusually forgiving.

Comment: i give ans that "I don't know "
but i want to know that ans so i ask here only
and i dont want to bluffing and exaggerating my experience here

Comment: Good for you.  You should accept @Dvd Prd's answer.  Look at item #4 - you can't SET a maximum for a string.  The only answer is "You can't set a MaxValue and a MinValue for a string.  It's only valid for dates, numbers, and single characters.  Attempting to set a MaxValue on a RangeValidator when the DataType is set to String will cause an exception to be thrown."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The RangeValidator control is used
>   to check that the user enters an input
>   value that falls between two values.
>   It is possible to check ranges within
>   numbers, dates, and characters.
>
> Note:
>
> 1.The validation will not fail if the input control is empty. Use the
>   RequiredFieldValidator control to make
>   the field required.
>
> 2.The validation will not fail if the input value cannot be converted to the
>   data type specified. Use the
>   CompareValidator control, with its
>   Operator property set to
>   ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck,
>   to verify the data type of the input
>   value.
>
> 3.Specifies the data type of the value to check. The types are:
>
> Currency Date Double Integer String
>
> 4.The RangeValidator control throws an exception if the value specified by
>   the MaximumValue or MinimumValue
>   property cannot be converted to the
>   data type specified by the Type
>   property.

source : 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1046041.aspx/1?how+to+use+RangeValidator+for+String+type+

Comment: this i know but is there any Exact value of length

Comment: I can't tell with for 100%, but based on the source I found it looks like the range-validator does not validate the length of a string but the ASCII-numbers of a string