# Min and max value of range validator?

Tags: asp.net, validation, rangevalidator

Range validator is used for string,integer and date.Can anybody give me ,min and max value of them?

Comment: possible of duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236677/what-is-the-string-maximum-and-minimum-value-in-range-validator-in-asp-net

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what you need to know?

Comment: If string,what is minvalue and max value?

Answer (score 1):

min and max length is euqal lenght of the int and double type...

Range validator control is a validator control which checks to see if a control value is within a valid range. The attributes that are necessary to this control are: MaximumValue, MinimumValue, and Type.

The RangeValidator control throws an exception if the value specified by the MaximumValue or MinimumValue   property cannot be converted to the data type specified by the Type property.

RangeValidator is not a good validator to validate the length of the string.You'd better use RegularExpressionValidator to validate it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1046041.aspx/1?how+to+use+RangeValidator+for+String+type+

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MaximumValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.maximumvalue.aspx) property to specify the maximum value of the validation range. If the value specified by this property fails to convert to the data type specified by the `BaseCompareValidator.Type` property, an exception is thrown.

So for instance, if you set the `Type` to `Integer` it would throw an exception if the value would be greater than [`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx).

> *If string,what is minvalue and max value?*

Here's the javascript RangeValidator function:

```
function RangeValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val) {
    var value = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate);
    if (ValidatorTrim(value).length == 0)
        return true;
    return (ValidatorCompare(value, val.minimumvalue, "GreaterThanEqual", val) &&
            ValidatorCompare(value, val.maximumvalue, "LessThanEqual", val));
}
```

As you'll see it compares [**ACSII codes**](http://www.asciitable.com/) for strings. ASCII values of '0' to '9' are 48  to  57, the ASCII values of 'a' to 'z' are 97  to 122 , and  the ASCII values of 'A' to 'Z' are 65  to 90. So `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` are the lower- and upper-bounds for these ASCII Codes in which the validator is` valid.

```
function ValidatorCompare(operand1, operand2, operator, val) {
    var dataType = val.type;
    var op1, op2;
    if ((op1 = ValidatorConvert(operand1, dataType, val)) == null)
        return false;   
    if (operator == "DataTypeCheck")
        return true;
    if ((op2 = ValidatorConvert(operand2, dataType, val)) == null)
        return true;
    switch (operator) {
        case "NotEqual":
            return (op1 != op2);
        case "GreaterThan":
            return (op1 > op2);
        case "GreaterThanEqual":
            return (op1 >= op2);
        case "LessThan":
            return (op1 < op2);
        case "LessThanEqual":
            return (op1 <= op2);
        default:
            return (op1 == op2);           
    }
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1046041.aspx/1?how+to+use+RangeValidator+for+String+type+

Note that you need an additional `RequiredFieldValidator` if you want to validate empty text.